# create graphic for theorem: hypotheis grouped implies in same line

Tags: graphics, theorems, arrows, layout

[image][image]i was writing my first document in latex, trying to emulate the notes i usually took in class.
When the theorem had many short hypothesis and thesis i used to write like the picture below to schematize it.
Is there a way to make this elegantly into latex?
Moreover an other thing i used to write on my notes was this long L to encase the short showing of some preposotions inside the proof of the theorem (second picture), is there a way to make it elegant in latex?
Thank you in advance and i apologize if i wasn't clear enough.
(If someone has a better idea for the title of the question, it is more than welcome

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Where are the pictures?

Comment: uploaded them, sorry for the mistake